# What is the difference between a Partial Order Set and a Group

Tags: group-theory, relations, order-theory

According to my what I read everywhere...

> A partially ordered set (also poset) formalizes and generalizes the intuitive concept of an ordering, sequencing, or arrangement of the elements of a set. **A poset consists of a set together with a binary relation** indicating that, for certain pairs of elements in the set, one of the elements precedes the other in the ordering.

And,

> **A group is a set equipped with a binary operation** that combines any two elements to form a third element in such a way that three conditions called group axioms are satisfied, namely associativity, identity and invertibility.

So in both cases there is a set with respect to a binary operation. Yet in posets we explore topics such as lattice and boolean algebra while in group theory there are semi-groups, monoids etc.

I just dont get the subtle difference between the two.

Comment: It's not as subtle a difference as you make it out to be; a binary _relation_ is a collection of pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $xRy$; you can think of it as a mapping from $S\times S\mapsto \{t,f\}$ where $S$ is the underlying set. By contrast, a group _operation_ is a mapping from $S\times S\mapsto S$; it takes two elements and gives you a third, rather than giving a true/false result.

Comment: Incidentally, you can view a poset as a category $\mathbf{C}$ where each hom-set $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(X, Y)$ has at most one element for each pair of objects $X, Y$ of $\mathbf{C}$; and a group as a category with exactly one object (and an additional requirement that each morphism in the category be invertible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these are very different structures with very different requirements.

An operation is different than a relation. An operation is a function $A \times A \to A$ while a relation is simply a subset of $A \times A$. We can think of any relation also as a function $A \times A \to \{0, 1\}$. This way it becomes obvious that **an operation** is not the same as **a relation**.

To be more concrete for us to have **a group** noone requires from us to have ordering (even partial) between the elements of the group. While for **a partially ordered** set this ordering requirement is essential.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks, done.

Answer (score 0):

A poset requires a few properties as well: the relation must be transative/ reflexive/ asymmetric.

A group requires different properties:
the morphism must be invertable/ associative/ have an identity (this might be the same as reflextivity idk).

Another big difference is Poset diagrams allow for branching, while groups can be modeled by sequences (do to its properties).

Someone can hopefully fix my vocabulary on the subject…